# Good Environment, Social, and Governance Indicators to correlate with financial performance of PE

Tags: research

I am trying to see if there is a correlation between the Environment, Social, and Governance (ESG) performance and the financial performance of Private Equity (PE) funds.

Are there any suggestions for good indicators of ESG performance of Private Equity Funds. These indicators should be at the fund level (i.e. not asset level). If possible it would be preferable to have indicators which can be observed in a pre-investment phase (e.g. relating to the General Partner).

Comment: Your question is still worded rather confusingly.  Are you looking for fund-level indicators or investment-level indicators?  What is a "pre-investment phase"?

Comment: Thanks your right, I'm looking for fund-level indicators. Pre-investment meaning before the fund is actually started. This could for example be done by looking at earlier funds of the General Partner.

Comment: Before digging-up private equity data (which will take resources), at least confirm your hypothesis in the public markets. Look at an index of vice stocks vs an index of socially responsible stocks to see if there are persistent performance differences.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good idea. Any idea's for indices of responsible stocks?